# Cascade dropdown from PowerApps to SharePoint List Item

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps

I created cascade dropdown in PowerApps and I was wondering if there is an option to use those two columns from powerapps in shp list item itself as columns wtih dropdown function?

Tried connecting powerapps columns into shp

Answer (score 0):

You can create a SharePoint online list first and then customize the list forms using Power Apps to create cascaded drop downs on the SharePoint list forms.

This process is described in detail with step by step tutorials in below Microsoft official documentations:

1. [Customize a form for a SharePoint list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/business-apps/power-apps/get-started/create-your-first-custom-form)
2. [Customize a Microsoft Lists or SharePoint form by using Power Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/customize-list-form)
3. [Create dependent drop-down lists in a canvas app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/dependent-drop-down-lists)